# Fast coin change algorithm for maximum of 3 coins in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have greedy algorithm, which solves all possible solutions for coin change problem. The maximum amount of coins is 3. Minimum 1.
Example

> With coins {1,2,3,4} I want to make sum 10
>   So the program outputs

- (4+4+2)
- (3+3+4)

> For coins {4, 5, 8, 3} and sum 12 it's

- (3+4+5)
- (4+4+4)
- (4+8)

etc.

Problem is that my algorithm is very inefficient, because it involves many for cycles. I searched a lot but only found algorithms that only shows number of solutions or coins variations for infinite number of coins.

My function. Coins are sorted in ascending order before.

```
void Count (int coins[], int cash, int n) {
    int or = 3; // Begin with a+b+c for or=2 its a+b, or=1 its a
    int i1,i2,i3;
    int sum;
    int result = 0;
    if (coins[0]*3 > cash) {
        or = 2;
    }
    if (coins[0]*2 < cash) {
        for (i1 = 0; i1<n; i1++) {
            if (or >= 2) {
                for (i2 = i1; i2<n; i2++) {
                    if (or==3) {
                        sum = coins[i1] + coins[i2];
                        for (i3=i2; i3<n; i3++) {
                            if (sum+coins[i3] == cash) {
                                printf("%d = %d + %d + %d\n", cash, coins[i1], coins[i2], coins[i3]);
                                result++;
                                break;
                            } else if (sum+coins[i3] > cash) {
                                if (i3==i2 && i2==i1) {
                                    or--;
                                    i2 = -1;
                                    i1 = 0;
                                } else if (i3==i2) {
                                    i2 = n;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        sum = (coins[i1] + coins[i2]);
                        if (sum == cash) {
                            printf("%d = %d + %d\n", cash, coins[i1], coins[i2]);
                            result++;
                        } else if (sum > cash) {
                            if (i2==i1) {
                                or--;
                                i1 = -1;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int o;
    if (coins[0]<=cash && coins[n-1] >= cash) {
        for (o=0;o<n;o++) {
            if (coins[o]==cash) {
                printf("%d = %d\n", cash, coins[o]);
                result++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Show what you've done so far. Explain why you think it's slow of inefficient. Show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From another SO post I wrote, in PHP.)

You can use a stack to enumerate valid combinations. The version below uses a small optimization, calculating if a minimum of the current denomination is needed. More than one least change combinations are returned if there are any, which could be restricted with memoization; one could also add an early exit if the current denomination could complete the combination with zero change. I hope the laconically commented code is self-explanatory (let me know if you'd like further explanation):

```php
function leastChange($coin_value,$inventory,$price){
  $n = count($inventory);
  $have = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    $have += $inventory[$i] * $coin_value[$i];
  }

  $stack = [[0,$price,$have,[]]];
  $best = [-max($coin_value),[]];

  while (!empty($stack)){

    // each stack call traverses a different set of parameters
    $parameters = array_pop($stack);
    $i = $parameters[0];
    $owed = $parameters[1];
    $have = $parameters[2];
    $result = $parameters[3];

    // base case
    if ($owed <= 0){
      if ($owed > $best[0]){
        $best = [$owed,$result];
      } else if ($owed == $best[0]){

        // here you can add a test for a smaller number of coins

        $best[] = $result;
      }
      continue;
    }

    // skip if we have none of this coin
    if ($inventory[$i] == 0){
      $result[] = 0;
      $stack[] = [$i + 1,$owed,$have,$result];
      continue;
    }

    // minimum needed of this coin
    $need = $owed - $have + $inventory[$i] * $coin_value[$i];

    if ($need < 0){
      $min = 0;
    } else {
      $min = ceil($need / $coin_value[$i]);
    }

    // add to stack
    for ($j=$min; $j<=$inventory[$i]; $j++){
      $stack[] = [$i + 1,$owed - $j * $coin_value[$i],$have - $inventory[$i] * $coin_value[$i],array_merge($result,[$j])];
      if ($owed - $j * $coin_value[$i] < 0){
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $best;
}
```

Output:

```php
$coin_value = [10,5,3,1];
$inventory = [0,1,3,4];
$price = 12;

echo json_encode(leastChange($coin_value,$inventory,$price)); // [0,[0,1,2,1],[0,1,1,4],[0,0,3,3]]

$coin_value = [10,5,3,1];
$inventory = [0,1,4,0];
$price = 12;

echo json_encode(leastChange($coin_value,$inventory,$price)); // [0,[0,0,4]]

$coin_value = [10,5,3,1];
$inventory = [0,1,3,0];
$price = 6;

echo json_encode(leastChange($coin_value,$inventory,$price)); // [0,[0,0,2]]

$coin_value = [10,5,3,1];
$inventory = [0,1,3,0];
$price = 7;

echo json_encode(leastChange($coin_value,$inventory,$price)); // [-1,[0,1,1]]
```

If you are also interested in the lowest *number* of coins, I think memoization could only work if we can guarantee that a better possibility won't be skipped. I think this can be done if we conduct our depth-first-search using the most large coins we can first. If we already achieved the same sum using larger coins, there's no point in continuing the current thread. Make sure the input inventory is presenting coins sorted in descending order of denomination size and add/change the following:

```
// maximum needed of this coin
$max = min($inventory[$i],ceil($owed / $inventory[$i]));

// add to stack 
for ($j=$max; $j>=$min; $j--){
```

Comment: Thanks!. Will try this. Php version works exactly how I need, but I have to translate it into C. Hope I'll find a way to get rid of the stack implementation.